# $.ajax( type: "POST" POST method to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to use the POST method in jQuery to make a data request. So this is the code in the html page:

```
<form>
Title : <input type="text" size="40" name="title"/>
<input type="button" onclick="headingSearch(this.form)" value="Submit"/><br /><br />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function headingSearch(f)
{
    var title=f.title.value;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "edit.php",
      data: {title:title} ,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.center').html(data); 
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

And this is the php code on the server :

```
<?php

$title = $_POST['title'];
if($title != "")
{
    echo $title;
}

?>
```

The POST request is not made at all and I have no idea why. The files are in the same folder in the wamp www folder so at least the url isn't wrong.

Comment: `return $title;` will not print anything in PHP, you'll need `echo $title;`.

Comment: what are the errors from the front end ajax call?

Comment: Use Firebug or similar to watch to see if any request is made at all

Comment: Are the files in the same directory?

Comment: Do you actually load jquery before that? If your js works fine and php is installed on the server, with ThiefMaster's changes, it returns data to the page correctly. And yes, use FF with Firebug to see the POST status and result.

Comment: jQuery is loaded in the <head> yes. I changed the code as you advised me and installed Firebug so this is the result :
Response Headersview source
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 4
Content-Type text/html
Date Thu, 07 Jun 2012 17:58:26 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Server Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.8

Comment: Request Headersview source
Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 10
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host localhost
Pragma no-cache
Referer http://localhost/homework/Site%20Beta/edit%20panel%20js/edit%20panel.htm
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your machine **and** set up on your web server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `data: {title: title}` to POST it correctly.

In the PHP code you need to `echo` the value instead of `return`ing it.

Answer (score 5):

Check whether title has any value or not. If not, then retrive the value using Id.

```
<form>
Title : <input type="text" id="title" size="40" name="title" value = ''/>
<input type="button" onclick="headingSearch(this.form)" value="Submit"/><br /><br />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function headingSearch(f)
{
    var title=jQuery('#title').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "edit.php",
      data: {title:title} ,
      success: function(data) {
    $('.center').html(data); 
}
});
}
</script>
```

Try this code.

In php code, use **echo** instead of **return**. Only then, javascript data will have its value.

Comment: Thanks for the code I posted in in the place of the old one, but unfortunately it did't help.

Comment: I changed it to echo immediately after ThiefMaster replied

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).on("submit", "#form-data", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url: "edit.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('.center').html(data); 
        }
    })
})
```

in the form the button needs to be `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

Id advice you to use a bit simplier method -

```
$.post('edit.php', {title: $('input[name="title"]').val() }, function(resp){
    alert(resp);
});
```

try this one, I just feels its syntax is simplier than the $.ajax's one...

Comment: I tried it even before writing to stack overflow. I tried your code, but still no change, thanks though.

Comment: so what does it do, alerts nothing? Or doesnt alert at all?

Comment: Do You use Firebug (in Mozilla) or Chrome to check whether you dont have any syntax mistake? (F12 to check if You dont have a red cross on the bottom right - click on it it'll show you scripts errors)

Answer (score 0):

```
function signIn()
{
    var Username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "auth_loginCode.jsp",
        data: {Username: Username, Password: Password},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.trim());
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)