# Send JSON formatted data from HTML form to api

Tags: html, json, ajax, forms

Read [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280241/html-form-data-to-json-format) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-should-i-use-servlets-and-ajax/4113258?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C47.4154#4113258) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936407/ajax-type-post-post-method-to-php) how to make my HTML form send JSON formatted code to my localhost:8000/api server.

Searching and trying for around three hours but nothing I try seems to work.

This is my actual code which doesn't sent any data (Network tab from Firefox Web Developer Tools doesn't show any interactions when Submit Button was pushed) and always runs through the error function.

Any support would be highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>API Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="input_form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="fullName">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    
    <script>
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'localhost:8000/api', // url where to submit the request
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                data: JSON.stringify($("form")),
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log("It works")
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log("Did not work")
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
This is the output of the Firefox Console:

```
[NoScript]:0 Prompt Hook installation file:///C:/html/Quiz/username.htm log.js:32:13
Freezing file:///C:/html/Quiz/username.htm DocumentFreezer.js:101:15
Unfreezing file:///C:/html/Quiz/username.htm DocumentFreezer.js:117:15
Diese Seite verwendet die nicht standardisierte Eigenschaft "zoom". Stattdessen sollte calc() in den entsprechenden Eigenschaftswerten oder "transform" zusammen mit "transform-origin: 0 0" verwendet werden. username.htm
Did not work username.htm:33:29
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(e), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(e, t), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(e), statusCode: statusCode(e), abort: abort(e), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(e)
, … }
​
abort: function abort(e)​
always: function always()​
catch: function catch(e)​
done: function add()​
fail: function add()​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader(e)​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType(e)​
pipe: function pipe()​
progress: function add()​
promise: function promise(e)
​
readyState: 0
​
responseJSON: undefined
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader(e, t)​
state: function state()
​
status: 0
​
statusCode: function statusCode(e)
​
statusText: "error"
​
then: function then(t, n, r)​
<prototype>: Object { … }
 error <empty string> username.htm:34:14
```

**Edit 2**
Source of the error seems to come from the line

```
data: JSON.stringify($("form")),
```

Trying out

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($("form")))
```

I receive the following result. Will continue checking tomorrow.

```
{"0":{"0":{},"1":{"jQuery363081041549224722111":{"events":{"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":15,"namespace":""}]}}}},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{"location":{"href":"file:///C:/html/Quiz/username.htm","origin":"null","protocol":"file:","host":"","hostname":"","port":"","pathname":"/C:/html/Quiz/username.htm","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery363081041549224722111":{"events":{"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":1,"selector":"[data-dismiss=\"alert\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"alert.bs.data-api"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":2,"selector":"[data-toggle^=\"button\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.button.data-api"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":4,"selector":"[data-slide]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.carousel.data-api"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":4,"selector":"[data-slide-to]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.carousel.data-api"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":6,"selector":"[data-toggle=\"collapse\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.collapse.data-api"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":8,"selector":".dropdown form","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.dropdown"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":9,"selector":"[data-toggle=\"dropdown\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.dropdown"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":11,"selector":"[data-toggle=\"modal\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.modal"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":13,"selector":"[data-toggle=\"tab\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.tab"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":13,"selector":"[data-toggle=\"pill\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.tab"},{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":7,"namespace":"bs.data-api.dropdown"}],"focusout":[{"type":"focusout","origType":"blur","guid":3,"selector":"[data-toggle^=\"button\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.button.data-api"}],"focusin":[{"type":"focusin","origType":"focus","guid":3,"selector":"[data-toggle^=\"button\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.button.data-api"}],"keydown":[{"type":"keydown","origType":"keydown","guid":10,"selector":"[data-toggle=\"dropdown\"]","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.dropdown"},{"type":"keydown","origType":"keydown","guid":10,"selector":".dropdown-menu","needsContext":false,"namespace":"bs.data-api.dropdown"}]},"focusout":1,"focusin":1}},"length":1}}
```

**Edit 3:**
Seems like I've got two issues here.

1. get the form data into JSON format
2. post JSON formatted data

on 2., even this code does not work

```
    <script>
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            const input_data = {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"};
            $.ajax({
                url: 'localhost:8000',
                type : "POST",
                dataType : 'json',
                data: input_data,               
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',

                success : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log("It works")
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log("Did not work")
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Console output:

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(e), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(e, t), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(e), statusCode: statusCode(e), abort: abort(e), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(e)
, … }
 error <empty string>
```

Comment: "doesn't sent any data" — How do you know? What does the Network tab in your browser's developer tools report?

Comment: "always runs through the error function" — Your error function does a bunch of logging. What do the logs show?

Comment: Are any other error messages reported?

Comment: `url: 'localhost:8000/api', // url where to submit the request` — That looks wrong … but I'd expect an error message in the console to shout about that at you.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify($("form"))` — That's an interesting value to pass to `JSON.stringify`. Have you tried logging what you are assigning to `data` to make sure it is what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
- Added "Network tab from Firefox Web Developer Tools doesn't show any interactions when Submit Button was pushed" explaination for why I believe nothing is send.
- Added also the Firefox Console output.
- Added console.log(JSON.stringify($("form"))) output which is definetly not what I expected

Answer (score -1):

you have to fix your ajax, it a matter of fact you are trying to send form data, not json so

```
  var form = $("#input_form");
 var formData = form.serializeArray();

...
 $.ajax({
 ...
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  data: formData,
....
})
```

make sure that your api doesn't have any frombody attribute

or if you want to send data as ajax

add id to a from input control

```
 <input type="text" id="fullName" placeholder="Name" >
```

and fix ajax

```
...
var fullName=$("#fullName").val();
...
 $.ajax({
  ...
data: JSON.stringify( {fullName:fullName),
....
```

if still doesn't work pls post your API action code